# ExcelJS freeze rows

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

I'm trying to freeze rows in ExcelJS but cannot get it to work.

I'm trying both

```
worksheet.views = [
{state: 'frozen', ySplit: 1}
];
```

and

```
workbook.addWorksheet(sheetName, {
views: [
{state: 'frozen', ySplit: 1}
]
});
```

but it doesn't work.

I also get the "We found a problem with...Do you want to recover as much.." warning when opening up the spreadsheet.

Anyone getting this to work? All I want to do is freeze the 7th row. I can do this in Excel itself

There's an Issue reported [here](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/151) that seems to say it's just not a feature in Excel itself. But I'm wondering why it corrupts the file too.

Comment: Just double-checking that you're using Node.js and the [`exceljs` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)...? I mistakenly read the question at first as being about Excel's own JavaScript API, but you used the [tag:excejs] tag and I see that `views` is something that the package talks about, so...

Comment: Correct, I'm using excelJS package and not Excel's JS API (didn't even know there was an official one..?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
workbook.addWorksheet(sheetName, {
    views: [{ state: "frozen", ySplit: 1 }],
});
```

It's working for me.

More details:

```
const Excel = require("exceljs");

const writeFile = async (sheetName, columns, list, file) => {
  let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  let sheet = workbook.addWorksheet(sheetName, {
    views: [{ state: "frozen", ySplit: 1 }],
  });
  sheet.columns = columns;

  for (const record of list) {
    sheet.addRow(record);
  }
  workbook.xlsx.writeFile(file);
};


const test = async () => {
  const columns = [
    { header: "Column1", key: "column1" },
    { header: "Column2", key: "column2" },
    { header: "Column3", key: "column3" },
  ];
  let list = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    let record = {};
    record.column1 = `line${i}_column1`;
    record.column2 = `line${i}_column2`;
    record.column3 = `line${i}_column3`;
    list.push(record);
  }
  const file = "c:/temp/test.xlsx";
  await writeFile("sheet1", columns, list, file);
};
test();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @You'll want to add `sheetName` as an argument to `writeFile`

Comment: This works, I want to be able to freeze just row 7, but not 1-6 or anything after 7. Doesn't look like this is possible within Excel itself though. Please let me know if you find anything

Comment: Thanks. Added sheetName as an argument

Comment: Excel only supports to freeze top 7 rows, and it doesn't support freeze just row 7. sample: ySplit: 7